# Terraform virtual machine extension Runs with Error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

The command below fails to execute the virtual machine extension when I try to run it.

```java
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "main" {
  name                 = "vm12345"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

 settings = <<SETTINGS  
 {  
    "fileUris": "https://www.githubprogrammercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1" 
    "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"  
}  
SETTINGS
}
```

But I still have the same problem, am I missing something?

```
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.test: compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: Long running operation terminated with status 'Failed': Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'vm12345'. Error message: \"Invalid handler configuration. Exiting. Error Message: Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text' with name '', namespace ''. \"."
```

Answer (score 0):

i suspect the structure of your code is not properly formatted.A definition is required here. When i did proper indentation, there wasn't an error in the above code.
From Terraform sample registry [here][1]

```
settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "fileUris": "https://www.githubprogrammercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1" 
    "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
    }
SETTINGS
tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
```

You can try above snippet and see if the error is shown again.
[1]: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_extension

Comment: Please format the code properly using code blocks.